# SharePoint 2016 skuID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office, 2016, visual-studio-2015

I have previously worked on SharePoint and could find a lot of references to SharePoint skuIDs of 2010, 2013. But, there aren't any references to SharePoint 2016.

I could get skuIDs from the server installed machine using the SharePoint management shell cmdlet: `(Get-SPFarm).Products` but here I couldn't refer them to any product as no such info provided.

Here are the results:

```
Guid
----

435d4d60-f4cf-421d-abc8-129e4b57f7a6

5db351b8-c548-4c3c-bfd1-82308c9a519b
```

where could I find the exact SharePoint 2016 skuIDs product info?

And what's this skuID made of and how to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it is as follows:

5DB351B8-C548-4C3C-BFD1-82308C9A519B = SharePoint 2016 Trail

716578D2-2029-4FF2-8053-637391A7E683 = SharePoint 2016 Enterprise

4F593424-7178-467A-B612-D02D85C56940 = SharePoint 2016 Standard

435d4d60-f4cf-421d-abc8-129e4b57f7a6 is present across all versions

Comment: Do you confirm these are the actual values?

Comment: Where did you get these from? Is there any documentation. If any it would be helpfull. Thank you!